# PHP Imagick hangs the whole server when converting PDF to Image

Tags: php, imagick

I'm using the extension Imagick on PHP to convert PDF files to images, PNG file to be specific.
The whole server always hang while the conversion is on-going. What I do is upload a bunch of PDF files, loop through it and the its pages to convert it to images.

Here is the code.

```
foreach ($uploaded_file as $key => $value) {
  $upload_file_path = $upload_path.'/'.$value->name;
  $imagick = new Imagick();
  $imagick->setResourceLimit(6, 1);
  $imagick->setResolution(300, 300);
  $imagick->readImage($upload_file_path);
  $pages = $imagick->getNumberImages();

  for ($x=0; $x<$pages; $x++) {
    $imagick->readImage($upload_file_path.'['.$x.']');
    $imagick->setImageFormat('png');
    $imagick->writeImage($image_path.'/page-'.$x.'.png');
  }

  $imagick->clear();
  $imagick->destroy();
}
```

I can't access other sites on the server while the conversion is on-going and the conversion takes too long. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: How many pdf files are you using and how many pages on average do they have?

Comment: You are reading in the PDF at density 300, which is more than 4 times the default density (72). Thus it will increase the file size by 16x from that when using the default density. If your PDF file is large inches, then you may be exceeding your available RAM. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#massive  for processing large images.

Comment: @admcfajn I have a template in which I upload 32 PDF files that have a total of 95 pages and another template that contains 95 pages.

Comment: @fmw42 yes I'm converting it with a density of 300 so that the quality of the image won't break if the browser is zoomed in. I'll try your advice. Thanks

Comment: @fmw42 BTW I used the function setResourceLimit() of Imagick as I've read it does something with my problem, so I guess there's more to it.

Comment: You need to edit the ImageMagick policy.xml file. See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php

Comment: So far I've tried to edit my loop and I guess the hogging of memory was fixed. I put the clear() and destroy() inside my loop on each page so that their resources will be freed. I will now try with the large PDF to check if it still hangs  the server then try editing the policy.xml if it still persists.

Comment: I've fixed the memory hogging of Imagick, the only problem now is the site that runs the script cannot be accessed while the convert is on-going. Earlier it was the whole server that can't be accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[php-vips](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips) is faster at converting pdfs to pngs, you could try that.

I made you a sample program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Jcupitt\Vips;

for ($i = 1; $i < count($argv); $i++) {
  $image = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[$i]);
  $n_pages = $image->get("n-pages");
  echo($argv[$i] . " has " . $n_pages . " pages\n");

  for ($n = 0; $n < $n_pages; $n++) {
    echo("  rendering page " . $n . " ...\n");
    $page = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[$i], [
      "dpi" => 300,
      "page" => $n,
      # this enables image streaming
      "access" => "sequential"
    ]);
    $page->writeToFile($argv[$i] . "_page_" . $n . ".png");
  }
}
```

I can run it like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ../convert-vips.php nipguide.pdf 
nipguide.pdf has 58 pages
  rendering page 0 ...
...
  rendering page 57 ...
107808:31.72
```

So it made 58 pngs in 32 seconds and needed a max of 110mb of ram. It doesn't create any temporary files -- that 110mb covers everything.

png is a very slow file format. If you save as jpg instead, it takes about 6s for everything.

I tried a version of your imagick code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i < count($argv); $i++) {
  $imagick = new Imagick();
  $imagick->setResourceLimit(6, 1);
  $imagick->setResolution(300, 300);
  $imagick->readImage($argv[$i]);
  $pages = $imagick->getNumberImages();
  echo($argv[$i] . " has " . $pages . " pages\n");

  for ($x = 0; $x < $pages; $x++) {
    echo("  rendering page " . $x . " ...\n");
    $imagick->readImage($argv[$i] . "[" . $x . "]");
    $imagick->setImageFormat("png");
    $imagick->writeImage($argv[$i] . "_page_" . $x . ".png");
  }

  $imagick->clear();
  $imagick->destroy();
}
```

Running that I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ../convert-imagick.php nipguide.pdf 
nipguide.pdf has 58 pages
  rendering page 0 ...
...
  rendering page 57 ...
255640:223.26
```

So 220s (almost 7x slower) and 260mb of memory. That memory use isn't the whole story -- at 300 DPI, imagick will make a 65mb file in /tmp for each page, so it needs about 5gb of storage in total.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this library, I used PNG because when I'm converting to JPEG some pages get a full black page even when I change the backround color.

Comment: Open an issue on the libvips tracker if you find a PDF which doesn't work, I'd be curious to see: https://github.com/libvips/libvips/issues

Comment: I updated the example to work a page at a time. This means it'll work for PDFs which change page size in the document.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a hard time installing libvips on windows. I got the windows binaries and I'm currently stuck how to work it with PHP, I don't know where to put these binary files. Do I need to copy the files inside the php folder? Btw I'm using xampp

Comment: Sorry, php-vips doesn't work on windows right now, the glue layer has not been ported: https://github.com/libvips/php-vips-ext  It shouldn't be hard to fix, but someone needs to volunteer.

Comment: Oh I see, on the linux, Ubuntu to be specific, it will be easy to install right? I just have to follow the instructions as is.

Comment: Okay so I've already finished installing the binaries and pecl. I've a question, php extensions on the php.ini file has a format of ```extension=php_imagick.dll```, should i include the vips as stated on the installation instruction like this ```extension=vips.so``` or ```extension=php_vips.dll```

Comment: Okay so after reading php.ini, I found out that dll and so are for windows and linux respectively. So I've tried to include the extension as ```extension=php_vips.so``` and it seems that vips is not detected when i use phpinfo(). I'll try to change it as vips.so instead of php_vips.so

Comment: vips still not detected even if I included the extension on php.ini. I went to the extension_dir of my php and found that there's no vips.so, will there be a problem if it's not found there?

Comment: Hi friend, so far I've successfully got it working but I've encountered an error saying that function vips_image_new_from_file() is undefined. I checked the Image.php file and confirmed that it is missing.

Comment: Update: It's working now but I've encountered another error ```vips_image_get: field "n-pages" not found```

Comment: I would guess your libvips has not been configured with PDF support. Open an issue on the php-vips tracker, it's a better place to fix installation issues than SO comments. https://github.com/libvips/php-vips-ext/issues/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the content of the PDF, conversion might indeed be exceedingly onerous. There's precious little you can do about it.

You already tried to lower the total number of threads to 2, but there's still memory, I/O latency and CPU resources to be taken into account -- and you don't know whether the server can employ more than two threads.

What you **maybe** can do is try and lower the I/O and CPU priority of the running process using `nice` and `ionice`, **if they are available**. You need to have a suitable platform (Linux, BSD or similar), and access to the `nice` and `ionice` tools; and you need a dedicated-executable PHP process (probably not FastCGI, then) and to be able to query its PID.

On a Linux system you might try and outsource the conversion to the ImageMagick binary, and wrap it in `nice` and `ionice` to make it go easy -- and slow.

Another possibility is to see whether you can use `ghostscript` instead of Imagick.

Comment: I'm not sure if using ionice would be nice because I need the uploaded files to be converted once it is uploaded. From what I've read, ionice is like a cron job management and also, Imagick cannot read PDF files without ghostscript, so I guess I'm already using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my findings and a solution for my situation I think can be insightful.

I have noticed it is much faster to create a new `imagick` instance per page, than to try to read the whole file and then let it 1) read the amount of pages and 2) let it iterate on all the pages.

I only want the first up to 10 pages of the PDF file. When I have a PDF file of 50 pages (most is only text and only 450KB), it will really matter which way you read this file.

In this way it will simply start reading from the first page and will try to read up till 10 pages. In case there are less than 10 pages, as soon as imagick throws an error, it will realize it has reached the end of the pages and will stop iterating.

```php
<?php
$reachedLastPage = false;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10 && empty($reachedLastPage); $i++) {
    $im = new imagick();
    $im->setResolution(300,300);
    try {
        $im->readimage($tempFile.'['.$i.']');
        if ($im->valid()) {
            $im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
            $im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_WHITE);
            $im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
            $im->setImageCompressionQuality(60);
            $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');

            $extraFile = microtime(true).'__pdfpage'.".".strtolower('jpg');
            $im->writeImage(rtrim($targetPath) . $extraFile);

            if (is_file(rtrim($targetPath) . $extraFile)) {
                $imageArray[] = $extraFile;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(ImagickException $e) {
        $reachedLastPage = true;
    }
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
}
?>
```

To give more insight of my other attempts.

1. I first tried read the whole pdf file and then use `getNumberImages()` and `setIteratorIndex()` to set a loop and read the individual pages. For imagick to read the whole thing will take a long time already without even starting to handle all the pages.
2. It is also possible to use a lightweight instance of imagick to see how many pages there is, it would have been a more neater solution than to let imagick try to read a page that doesn't exist:

```
$im->pingImage($tempFile);
$nrOfPages = $im->getNumberImages();
```

However this took in my test already 10 seconds, just to read the number of pages. That's why I ended up with the above method.